# Как создать txt файл

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть массив случайных фраз при нажатии на кнопку выдает случайную из массива, Вопрос: Как при помощи JS, или HTML5 или jQuery при нажатии на ссылку с фразой создавать txt файл и записывать эту фразу туда, искал в интернете еще ничего даже близко не нашел. Помогите плз хотя-бы литературой на эту тему, пример кода было бы совсем волшебно!

Вот код массива>>

```js
function my_alert() {
var text =
["Сегодня прекрасный день",
"Вам определённо повезёт",
"Не грусти. Всё будет хорошо",
"Улыбнись",
":) :) :)",
"Ты сегодня лучше всех"];
min = 0;
max = text.length-1;
out = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text[out];
}
```

```html
<p>Случайная фраза:</p>
<a href="#"><p id="text"></p></a>
<button id="ok" onClick="my_alert()">ОК</button>
```

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, вот блин, опередил ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для таких целей есть специальные плагины. Я использовал этот:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Или ещё можно так:

```js
var downloadURL = function(url, name) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if(name == undefined || name == ''){name = url};
    link.setAttribute('href',url);
    link.setAttribute('download',name);
    onload = link.click();
};
$(function() {
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    downloadURL('data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,'+$('#text').val(), 'Название');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Скачать">
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если вы его уже использовали не могли бы кинуть пример?. если вас не затруднит

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛюбимов, это было давно. Я делал редактор web кода и мне нужно было, что бы он сохранял код в файле

Comment: Я и спрашивал если не затруднит=) но все равно спасибо

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!zlURBaZJ!Xd09PF9E4nnqj67e99fbEcSH0F4vdum-Onw9NTaNI-4 Вот я делал, только я там не всё сделал в редакторе :)

Comment: обязательно плагин? Текстовый файл? По моему это можно в одну строчку по data-протоколу.

Comment: @nick_n_a, в принципе да. Не подумал сразу

Comment: @nick_n_a, редактировал ответ

Comment: @nick_n_a, ну вышеуказанный плагин - это просто самая популярная и кроссбраузерная обертка всего этого дела. Внутри оно то самое и есть. Но судя по вопросу лучше автора не морочить подробностями.

Comment: Прошу уточнить, с какого IE эта фишка работает? На "производстве" куда не кинешься везде IE. Установить повсемесно другое - не представляется возможным. Сам сохранял похожим образом. Только в IE8 не получилось.

Comment: @Yuri Все просто супер работает прям как надо. Первый раз мне ответили так подробно и так много и так правильно спасибо вам огромное вы помогли мне разобраться и сэкономили кучу времени!!!!

Comment: @nick_n_a Мне главное чтоб в google chroom работало. Там все гуд

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Доступ к файловой системе из браузера запрещен

Comment: Не совсем верно, доступ к чему попало - да, запрещен.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov объемный ответ=), а если будет создан файл заранее в него помещать, фразу а по ссылке скачивать файл?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛюбимов вам нельзя сохранять в какую попало папку, просто создать файл в заранее предусмотренную браузером папку - можно. Посмотрите мой комментарий к вопросу.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛюбимов ну и да, вариант "создать файл на серваке а по ссылке лишь качать" тоже возможен. Насколько я понимаю, задача чисто для самообучения или есть практическая цель?

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Спасибо за разъяснение, цель есть но я еще не знаю, сказали на работе сделать, я так понял туда потом будут массивы данных посылать=)

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, в общем в контексте задачи Ваш ответ "Никак" - ложен, рекомендую удалить или поправить